# QTextBrowser: How to highlight a clicked line

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

In my textbrowser, I've already implemented the mousePress and found the line number when clicked. Now I want to highlight where I clicked i.e., change its background color. I knew line is different with block. Luckily in my text one line is one block. So What I did is to manipulate the block format by cursor, listed as follows:

```
QTextCursor cur = mytextBrowser->textCursor();
QBlockFormat f;
f.setBackground(Qt::red);
cur.selection(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
cur.setBlockFormat(f);
cur.setPosition(startPos);//I calculate this startPos before. It's where the cursor should be
mytextBrowser->setTextCursor(cur);
```

However, the result is odd. When I first click the text, nothing happened, sometimes maybe selected a word. Then I click again, that previous line and the above line would be highlighted. I don't understand why this happened. Could anyone give me some solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even compile. It uses `QBlockFormat` class that doesn't exist and `cur.selection` with invalid argument. Did you just type it out of your head? Anyway, why don't you use `LineUnderCursor` instead? The following code works fine for me:

```
void MainWindow::on_textBrowser_cursorPositionChanged() {
  QTextCursor cur = ui->textBrowser->textCursor();
  QTextBlockFormat f;
  f.setBackground(Qt::red);
  cur.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
  cur.setBlockFormat(f);
  ui->textBrowser->setTextCursor(cur);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I used the same way as you gave. Those are typos because the real code is in a computer without internet so I have to type them manually. Anyway, in this method, the problem is that when I click a line, say 5, it has no respond. However, next time I click another line, the line 5 would be highlighted. Would you please tell  me why??

Comment: Basically, this is the right answer. But I think "ui->textBrowser->setTextCursor(cur)" is not needed because it may causes additional highlight. Also, in my program, I calculate the cursor position where clicked and use the setCursorPosition. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use it works for both QTextEdit and QTextBrowser:

textBrowser is QTextBrowser in example below.

```
        void MainWindow::on_textBrowser_cursorPositionChanged(){
          QTextBrowser::ExtraSelection selection ;
          QColor lineColor = QColor(201, 191, 253, 15);
          selection.format.setBackground(lineColor);
          selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat::FullWidthSelection, true);
          selection.cursor = ui->textBrowser->textCursor();
          selection.cursor.clearSelection();
          extraSelections.append(selection);
          ui->textBrowser->setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
        }
```